# Is it possible to pass some files through a POST API to a Cloud Foundary Application?

Tags: flask, cloud-foundry

I have 2 Cloud foundry applications.
On First application i have pushed a windows exe which is having 0 instances
Manifest.yml of this app looks like this:-

```
    applications:

- name: sampleApp
  stack: windows2012R2
  instances: 0
  memory: 512M
  no-route: true
  health-check-type: none
  buildpacks: 
  - binary_buildpack
```

I have created a POST Flask API on other cloud foundry application and this API will collect a file from user.

Now i want to run sampleApp with this file, can anyone help me how i can link both these applications?

Answer (score 0):

At first glance, this might seem easy but when deployed to Cloud Foundry both of your applications are entirely separate. They run in different containers and on different OS stacks (Python is Linux, your exe is Windows). It's not as easy as just shelling out and running an external process.

To make something like this work you need to add a communication channel between the two applications. It's common to have one or more web processes that send messages to a pool of one or more workers (independently scaled) that perform potentially CPU/RAM intensive tasks.

How you communicate between the two is up to you. You could make REST endpoints, use gRPC or a message broker (STOMP, RMQ, etc...). You just have to agree so that your web UI knows how to pass messages along to the workers.

If you can't modify your exe, like it's provided by a third party, then you'd need to wrap it with an application that can perform the communication and then shell out and run your exe.